# Spring Data: Method with annotation @Query doesn't work as expected

Tags: java, junit, transactions, spring-data, dao

I try to cover my `Repository` code with `junit` tests but unexpectedly I am facing the following problem:

```
  @Test
    @Transactional
    public void shoudDeactivateAll(){

        /*get all Entities from DB*/
        List<SomeEntity> someEntities = someEntityRepository.findAll();

/*for each Entity set 1 for field active*/
        someEntities.forEach(entity -> 
        {entity.setActive(1);

/*save changes*/
        SomeEntityRepository.save(entity);});

        /*call service, which walks through the whole rows and updates "Active" field to 0.*/
        unActiveService.makeAllUnactive();

/*get all Entities again
        List<SomeEntity> someEntities = SomeEntityRepository.findAll();

/*check that all Entities now have active =0*/
        someEntities.forEach(entity -> {AssertEquals(0, entity.getActive());});
    }
```

where: 
`makeAllUnactive()` method is just a `@Query`:

```
 @Modifying
            @Query(value = "update SomeEntity e set v.active=0 where v.active =1")
            public void makeAllUnactive();
```

And: `someEntityRepository` extends `JpaRepository`

This test method return `AssertionError`: `Expected 0 but was 1.`

it means that `makeAllUnactive` didn't change the status for Entitites OR did chanches, but they are invisible.

Could you please help me understand where is "gap" in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the query you have:

```
@Query(value = "update SomeEntity e set v.active=0 where v.active =1")
```

you should rather have changed it into:

```
@Query(value = "update SomeEntity e set e.active=0 where e.active =1")
```

if that does not work, try flushing after running `SomeEntityRepository.save(entity);`

EDIT:

You should enable `clearAutomatically` flag in the `@Modifying`, so that `EntityManager` will get updated. However keep it mind that it may also cause loosing all the non-flushed changes. For some more reading take a look:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.M1/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa.modifying-queries

Comment: oh, 'v.active' is my typos. in code: 'e.active' ignore it :)